# Multiplying and dividing composite functions

Tags: functions

I'm given:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1}$$

$$g(x) = \sqrt{\log2x}$$

I'm asked to multiply $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and to divide them, and then state the domain for both.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make them better :/

Comment: Seriously?  Why did you delete your previous post?  I had an answer almost completely typed up and then I get notified that the question was deleted.  Then you post the exact same question again.  And the first one was formatted better.

Comment: my apologies tilper, I tried fixing it but got a ton of $ instead, so I tried to redo the formulas using demos, but even that didn't work

Comment: You need to show some of your thoughts or this will be closed. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Rules for reals : $\dfrac *{\neq 0},\quad\sqrt{\ge 0},\quad\log(>0)$

Answer (score -2):

Domain is x>1 because radicals have to be positive, logs can't be 0, and x cannot equal 1 or else you divide by zero which is undefined. You can simply multiply f(x) and g(x) together...here is a link if you have forgotten.

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/fcnops.htm

Comment: Not really. What is the product for $x=\dfrac 12$?